# Python- Finding out if 2 values are equal while one is less than or equal to the other two

Tags: python

I'm implementing a function that tests for ultrametricity(?) in sequences. Specifically
I'm using the 3 point condition

I have trouble with part of my code.
I have a sequence of 3 numbers and I want to return true if 2 numbers are equal and one is less than or equal to the two that are equal.

For example:

Input: [0.8,0.8,0.6]

Output: True

---

Input: [0.4,0.8,0.8]

Output: True

---

Input: [0.6, 0.7, 0.8]

Output: False

---

Input:[0.8, 0.9, 0.8]
Output: False

Comment: To be clear, the question is way more complex and this is just a small part of the coding. Here's an image of the problem if you think I'm simply asking for answers... http://i.imgur.com/wKrjPPF.png

Comment: I was thinking of doing a while loop but I'm not sure it will give the right answer.

I put my current code above. I am hesitant in posting it in case my classmates copy it...lol

Comment: "If 2 numbers are equal and one is less than or equal to the two that are equal." -> Input: [0.8, 0.8, 0.8] Output: False ???

Comment: my mistake, sorry. my mind is clearly not functioning right now :(

Comment: I guess the first condition specifies that there must be *exactly* two elements which are equal, while the third element must be less than the two of them (or equal, but in this case there will be three same numbers, which does not satisfy first requirement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is only three different conditions:

```
def equal3(a, b, c):
  return (c <= a == b) or (b <= a == c) or (a <= b == c)
```

You call it as `equal3(*[0.9, 0.8, 0.8])` where `*` means you want to unpack the list.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining the asterisk. I never knew that it did that

Answer (score 7):

Quick solution:

```
def do_compare(arr):
    a, b, c = sorted(arr)
    return a <= b == c
```

Comment: Wow, so simple... I must be lacking sleep to be unable to come to this solution

thanks.

Comment: Should be arr[0] <= arr[1] == arr[2]

Comment: When I answered, OP required "[0.8, 0.8, 0.8]" to be false. That requirement seemed to have been deleted, though. Will rollback my answer.